# Error when adding ext.grid.panel into ext.form.panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs4

I have this grid and form panels. I want to add a grid of data into the form panel and still have buttons from the form panel.

```
      myGrid= Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
            layout: {
                type: 'fit'
            },

            id: 'gridId',
            title: null,
            store: myDataStore,
            columns: [{
                header: 'header 1',
                dataIndex: 'index_1',
                width: 120
            }, {
                header: 'header 2',
                dataIndex: 'index_2',
                width: 120
            }, {
                header: 'header 3',
                dataIndex: 'index_3',
                width: 120
            }],
            stripeRows: true
        })

        formPanel= Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
            id:'panelId',

            items:[myGrid],
            buttons: [{
                 // cancel, save, other buttons
            }]
        })
```

But I get this error

```
HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy
```

what do I do wrong?

Comment: I don't see any error in this code. I've got working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/wPWxN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot semicolons after your `Ext.create()` config.

Seems to work just fine here. I made a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/WGgR8/1/